# Can't Import libraries for SQLhelper class

Tags: c#, sql, nuget, enterprise-library, sqlhelper

I'm trying to remove duplicate code to connect to SQL database, create stored procedure parameters, etc.

I found that `SQLHelper` class requires Enterprise library. So as we use NuGet, I downloaded the package and referenced it in the project.

I then would want to import it with "using", but I can't import the following:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
```

as it can't find the assembly.

With Enterprise Library 6 NuGet automatically referenced two assemblies: `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common` and `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`

Under neither of these I could find the `SQLHelper` class.

Can somebody tell me what do I do wrong, and how can I use the class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a nuget package for just the sqlhelper (databasehelper): https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsSqlHelper/

I think that that will contain everything you need.